# R.java cannot be resolved after imported opencv library in android studio

Tags: android, opencv

I am using xubuntu 14.04 and I am using the latest version of android studio which is 1.4 (September 2015). My sdk platform tools is 23.0.1, build tools version is also 23.0.1. I am using API Level 15 as my project's sdk version to target a lot of devices. I have imported the opencv (2.4.11) properly and I can import its libraries. When I rebuild project I get the same error. R.java cannot be resolved. How can I fix this? My java version is 1.8.0_60.

Here is the error:
[image]

This error occured when I cleaned the project.

Comment: I recommend use JDK 1.7. Sometimes with a clean and build Android Studio get class R. Be sure your import class R is correct too. Check your gradle for wrong syntaxis... A little bit more information would be fine.

Comment: looks like an issue with compileSdkVersion. What version are you using?

Comment: API Level 15, buildversion 23.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of no of methods might have exceeded than 65k, can you clean and build and paste the error here.

Comment: no avail. I have rebuilded the project.But as the same, I get 120 errors concluded with "R.java file cannot be resolved".

Comment: Check gradle console and event log !! there should be some error.

Answer (score 0):

Please go onto Android Studios and do an Invalidate and Restart.

You can do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart".

If this does not work, please check whether all your resource references actually exist as sometimes, if you put in a resource reference incorrectly, your android will not run (for example, R.id.textbox is inside your xml but you have put R.id.texxtbox in your code)

You can also try to refresh grade by clicking on the "Refresh" button which you see below (the blue reversing arrow icon).

[image]